# Unexpected auto_increment behavior

Tags: mysql

When I create table in that way I have errors while inserting

```
create table if not exists users(
id INT,
email varchar(100),
user_name varchar(256),
user_last_name varchar(256),
phone varchar(50),
origin varchar(256),
birth_date date,
gender tinyint(1),
about_me text,
photo   int
)auto_increment 1;
alter table users add constraint pk_user primary key (id);

insert into users (gender) values(0);
```

But when I change definition of primary key like this `id INT primary key auto_increment`, inserting works fine. I am confused about what 
is difference?

Comment: I believe the former just sets where auto-increment values would start, not defines a field as auto_increment.

Comment: @Uueerdo Ok, but how to define field as auto_increment in another way? Because I already tried id INT auto_increment, and add primary key using alter statement

Comment: What is your question? The second way you mentioned is perfectly fine. The difference has been outlined by @Uueerdo

Comment: @dognose You are right, but I wondering how to create a named primary key that would by auto incremented

Comment: @user3378876 you can't do this. Refer to the documenteation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html *The name of a PRIMARY KEY is always PRIMARY, which thus cannot be used as the name for any other kind of index.* Even your approach with the constraint would end up beeing named **PRIMARY**